# How to call a module function in access though php?

Tags: php, sql, ms-access

I have a customised function for **soundex** in a module in Microsoft Access 2007.
It is declared public, in the same database as the table.

When i execute the query in Access, it works. But when i query it through PHP, it says

**Undefined function 'soundex' in expression**

Help me out.

Comment: Not possible... Any reason you're using Access? Thought about migrating it to MySQL or SQL Server - this would allow proper Store Procs and functions.

Comment: Yeah... i have to use Microsoft Access due to license issues at the company. I know mysql is free, but i can't use it.

Comment: Just a thought, but table-level data macros have been introduced in A2010, and it might be possible to program your Soundex() function in that (though the macro language is still fairly primitive -- dunno how it does with CASE SELECT), and then you could make it the equivalent of a trigger when the name fields are updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think thats possible. Your JET driver providing access to the database through PHP does not know about your user defined function, so you can not call it.